# filling array with financial data from html using python

Tags: python

I have this [income statement](http://gambler-restaurant-15377.bitballoon.com/) and I was curious how some of you would go about extracting the data from the html into an array. I posted what I have concocted. Any comments regarding ways of improve.  Would be interested in seeing ways of doing it using stdlib, panads, numpy, whatever. Thanks

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import OrderedDict

url = r'http://gambler-restaurant-15377.bitballoon.com/'

r = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent" : b'Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.2; U; zh-cn) Presto/2.6.30 Version/10.6'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

financial_statement=OrderedDict()
for row in soup.find_all('table', attrs={'id':'dollarTable'})[0].find_all('tr'):
    row_items = []
    for item in row:
        try:
            row_items.append(str(item.get_text(strip=True)))
        except (AttributeError, ValueError):
            # headers dont have a tr tag, and thus raises AttributeError
            # 'Fiscal Year Ending in 2011' raises ValueError
            pass
    financial_statement[row_items[0]]=row_items[1:]



('For year ending Dec,', ['2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015'])
('Revenues', ['306,057.0', '--', '--', '733,438.0', '390,625.0', '407,708.0', '110,000.0', '18,833.0', '10,417.0'])
```

Comment: Does your code work? If not, what is not working?

Comment: "Would be interested in seeing ways of doing it using stdlib, panads, numpy, whatever." Usually, one shows their attempts at using such a library, and ask for feedback if it's not working as expected. If you're looking for a review of your code in general: there is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: it does, however I was thinking a better solution would be to somehow map each item to the associated year (which is the first item in the dict). So for example:  '2007'  'Revenues' should be associated with  the value '306,057.0'

Comment: Ok,  thanks evert. wasn't aware of code review.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import OrderedDict

url = r'http://gambler-restaurant-15377.bitballoon.com/'

r = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent" : b'Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.2; U; zh-cn) Presto/2.6.30 Version/10.6'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

financial_statement=OrderedDict()
for row in soup.find_all('table', attrs={'id':'dollarTable'})[0].find_all('tr'):
    row_items = []
    for item in row:
        try:
            row_items.append(str(item.get_text(strip=True)))
        except (AttributeError, ValueError):
            # headers dont have a tr tag, and thus raises AttributeError
            # 'Fiscal Year Ending in 2011' raises ValueError
            pass
    financial_statement[row_items[0]]=row_items[1:]



('For year ending Dec,', ['2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015'])
('Revenues', ['306,057.0', '--', '--', '733,438.0', '390,625.0', '407,708.0', '110,000.0', '18,833.0', '10,417.0'])
```

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable to include the essential parts of the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) here, and provide the link for reference.